# Change src from img, but only the one who was clicked in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to change the src from the specific image clicked only, but it's changing all images. All the solutions I could find show elements in loop, which is not the case here:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>         
    <img :src="icon" @click="change" />
  </div>
  <div>          
    <img :src="icon" @click="change" />
  </div>
  <div>                
    <img :src="icon" @click="change" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      icon: 'index.png'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.icon = 'icon.png'
    }
  }
})
        
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they all update at once is that they all get their `src` value from the same property. If you're wanting to change them individually, they'll all need their own properties and modifications to the `change` method so it knows what to update.

Try doing something like this:

```
<template>
  <img :src="icon1" @click="change('icon1')" />
  <img :src="icon2" @click="change('icon2')" />
  <img :src="icon3" @click="change('icon3')" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      icon1: "index.png",
      icon2: "index.png",
      icon3: "index.png",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change(prop) {
      this[prop] = "icon.png";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I created a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-for-stackoverflow-post-e8immr?file=/src/App.vue:299-457) that should show it in action.